# Actualizar la contraseña en stackoverflow

Tags: discussion

Necesito actualizar mi contraseña en stackoverflow pero no encuentro un formulario donde hacerlo.
Gracias por cualquier ayuda

Comment: https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/mylogins/81972 De nada.

Comment: Esto parece más una pregunta para Meta. Otra forma, además de la que te dieron, puede ser desloguearte, poner que olvidaste la contraseña y con el link que te envía al correo de recuperación, crear una nueva.